# Fragment theme not appliying

Tags: android, fragment, android-theme

I would like to change dynamically the theme of my Fragment.
I have tried these solutions:

1st try, set the getTheme method on the activity. It only changes the colors of the activity:

```
@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
    theme.applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme_RED, true);
    return theme;
}
```

2nd try not changing anything:

```
final Context contextThemeWrapper = new 

ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme_RED);
LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.from(contextThemeWrapper);
final View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list, container, false);
```

3rd try work only for activity, not fragment:
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_RED);

Any help is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have found that floatingbutton have the good color when i apply theme to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

as google says we must inflate our theme before **super.oncreate()**

inside your activity or fragment and in  *oncreate()* or on *oncreateview()* simply add the code below:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_RED);
```

Comment: are you trying to change your theme with a button or sth? and do you reload your fragment after button click?

Comment: I'm trying to change theme with button and listview in fragment.

Comment: check this one and see if it does help you
https://www.hidroh.com/2015/02/25/support-multiple-themes-android-app-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the link but it is for activity not for fragment.